# Center 3 divs (one with a variable width, 2 with fixed widths) inside another div

Tags: css, layout, html

I am trying to achieve the following:

Center 3 div tags within an outer fixed with div

Two of the inner div tags to be centered are of a fixed (the images on the left and right).

One of the inner div tags (the one with text in the center) has a variable width. **Note: I also need this text div to be vertically centered.**

Here is what I am trying to achieve: http://uploadpic.org/storage/2011/hDGazBwWF2QHzGipwkyJ7ESsX.gif

How can this be achieved? I have found answers to similar questions, but not exactly what I have described.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle`.  Here's a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/ujoket/1/edit

Comment: I was going to put the same. However there's some issues with `display:inline-block;` and IE
For more info on vertical align [CSS display: inline-block: why it rocks, and why it sucks](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Comment: [Just IE7 I think](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block)?  fix here though http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Comment: 'The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.' according to w3school.
Apparently I was quite wrong!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Works like a charm! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me with this!